# A jQuery selector for all children of a parent that are not from a class

Tags: jquery

I want to capture the click event of all the children of a tr element, without those who have 'notClickable' class. I also want to have all elements that have a 'clickable' class in my selector.

```
<div class='clickable'>
    This is clickable
</div>

...

<tr>
    <span class='notClickable'>
        This is not clickable
    </span>
    <div>
        <span>This is clickable</span>
        <span class='notClickable'>This is not clickable</span>
    </div>
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.clickable, tr CHILDREN:not(.notClickable)').click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Your second `notClickable` is not a child of `tr`, it's a grand-child. Do you mean all descendants?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to remove `CHILDREN` from selector as there is no `CHILDREN` element.

```
$('.clickable, tr :not(.notClickable)').click(function() { ... })
```

Comment: even though it does what OP has asked for... it may not solve the actual problem because of event propagation

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing. Maybe he actually wants `span:not(.notClickable)`, so the DIVs won't be matched.

Comment: I know that there isn't a CHILDREN tag, I just wanted to point out that I want to select ALL children elements of the tr element, no matter whether they are td, span, div, p, etc. as soon as they don't have a 'notClickable' class. I don't want to write all possible children elements of the tr and I was asking whether there is a way that I can select all children, not only the span elements :)